# Algorithm Issue : Multiple Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm stuck trying to get the total number of pizzas eaten using django

*My model is like:*

```
class pizza_total_eated(Model.models):
     user           #fk to users
     pizza          #fk to pizzas
     total_eated    #total number of `pizza` eaten

"""
+------+-------+-------+
| user | pizza | total |
+------+-------+-------+
|  1   |   1   |   5   |
|  1   |   2   |   6   |
|  2   |   3   |   4   |

"""
```

This stores the total number of pizzas of a certain type eaten by a user. Basically I want to retrieve the total number of eaten pizza by users

When I just have one Pizza getting the total number eaten is easy:

```
pizza_total = pizza_total_eated.objects.filter(Pizza = 1)

for user in pizza_total:
    user.total_eated
```

But how can would i do this for *each user => each pizza*

```
for user in pizza_total
    for pizza in user.pizza
        pizza.total_eated     #user 1 -> pizza 1 so total_eated = 5
```

Comment: so you want to iterate over your entire table to create another data structure representing your entire table? why not just pass it to a template 'as-is' and iterate over it in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this alternate data structure:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    # pizza_stuff 
    # ...
    # ...

class PizzaEaten(models.Model):
    pizza = models.Foreingkey(Pizza)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Each time an User `u` eats a Pizza `p`, you would:

```
PizzaEtean.objects.create(user = u, pizza = p)
```

Then, if you want to query the number of Pizza's user u ate, just use:

```
PizzaEaten.objects.filter(user = u).count()
```

If you want to get the number of pizzas an User ate of each type, you can use Django annotation and do:

```
from django.db.models import Count
PizzaEaten.objects.values('user', 'pizza').annotate(eat_count = Count('id'))
```

You can read up the [django documentation on `values`and `annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#values) for why this works.
Basically, an annotation will be generated for each unique combination of values.
In your case, this means you get a Count for each user / pizza combination.

#### Sidenote:

This will also prevent race conditions as you won't be incrementing a counter field but inserting new records if need be.
You could also store additional (relevant) information on the `PizzaEaten` Model, such as when the user ate the Pizza.

Comment: For added goodness, make `PizzaEaten` the `through` table of a ManyToMany relationship from Pizza to User.

Comment: Yeah, sounds very good. Actually I just had one thing bothering me about that, but you'll probably be able to answer: if I do this, is it OK to have multiple PizzaEatean records with the same user / pizza combination?

Comment: Thank you for this answer Thomas & Daniel ! I changed my model and now  it is working fine. One question: if I have a very big amount of eaten pizzas (cause I love them :p) : How will be the performances to retrieve the Count for each type of Pizzas ?

Comment: All the calculations are handled in the database here; unless you have undersized hardware, you shouldn't run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need the Pizza_total_eated table:
Just have a Pizza table:

```
PIZZA_CHOICES = (
  ('t', 'Tomato'),
  ('c', 'Cheese')
)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(choices=PIZZA_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

And then the query would be:

```
Pizza.objects.values_list('user_id','type').annotate(total=Count('type'))
```

This query will return a list of 3tuple(the first value of the tuple is the user id, the second one is the pizza type and the third one is the total number of pizzas of this type the user ate):

```
 [(4, u't', 2), (4, u'c', 1), ...]
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood someting, but why would you call this object "Pizza"?
It might also become an issue that you have to change the source code when you want to add a pizza.

Comment: What do you mean by "you have to change the source code when you want to add a pizza"?

Comment: Say I now want to have a new pizza : pepperoni, then unless I'm missing something, you have to change the models.py file.

Comment: I took as granted that the pizza types are known in advance. Your code is more generic.

Comment: Thank you Thikonom : Sadly I need to be able to add more type of Pizzas in the future :)